# Prevent Dismissal of Modally Presented ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am presenting a `viewcontroller` modally and am trying to configure it where, when I re-enter the foreground after going to the background (i.e. I click a website link that redirects me out fo the app and then I navigate back to the app), I don't want the presented `viewcontroller` to be dismissed.

Is the only option to create a `navigationcontroller` stack? Hoping for a solution without this, and I couldn't find any existing commentary around this/am fairly new to all this. Any advice would be helpful.

My view hierarchy is...

1. Root MainTabBarVC
2. Load DummyMenuVC into MainTabBarVC `viewcontrollers`
3. Present on `shouldSelect` tabBarControllerDelegate method RealMenuVC
4. Tap RealMenuVC Button to present NextVC

I have #2 & #3 to be able to interact with the menu over the full context of any `tabBarItem` selected.

Comment: Instead of *presenting* it, load the VC as a Child View Controller and add its view as a subview, covering everything as if it was a modally presented controller.

Comment: A presented view controller is _not_ dismissed merely because you go into the background. Why do you this that it is? The app is simply suspended at the point where you are, and when you come back to the foreground, it is resumed at that point. If that's not what you are seeing, maybe your app is being _killed_ (terminated) in the background. To confirm that, put some logging in the app delegate `didFinishLaunching` and see it is called again when you resume your app.

Comment: @matt thanks for the comment. im not too familiar but that was the assumption i was trying to better explore as the presented VC continued to be dismissed when re-entering the foreground. that said, i performed the logging you had suggested and the app appears to neither terminate nor relaunch.

Comment: Well I don't know what "continued to be dismissed" means. If you are saying that you leave the app and when you return to it the presented view controller is no longer visible, that could be a bug in your program and you need to track it down. Perhaps _you_ are dismissing it without realizing it. But it is not dismissed automatically. In any case it sounds like that's what your question should be about.

Comment: @matt thank you for guiding me in the direction that the dismissal was programmatic at my own fault. i have pinned the cause and thank you again for helping me grow as a new developer

Comment: Glad you got it! You might answer your own question or delete the question, either way as you prefer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learned a presented vc isn't dismissed just because it goes into the background mode, and that something must have been programmatically integrated to trigger it.

I traced my issue to a notificationCenter observer I had included, which invoked a function that dismissed presented vcs.

Answer (score -1):

this solution work for me

```
modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```